# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en SQL doblemente agrupadas en un solo registro en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenos Noches estoy sufriendo con una consulta que estoy implementando a mi sistema.
Actualmente tengo las siguientes tablas:

Actividades: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tareas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla Tareas tiene el idactividad como foránea de la tabla Actividades, lo que quiero hacer es mostrar las tareas actuales, las tareas atrasadas según cada actividad.
Así me sale pero en consultas diferentes, lo que quiero hacer es que me muestren en un solo registro.

Con esta consulta obtengo las tareas actuales por cada actividad:

```
select actividad,count(t.id) as tareas_actuales 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
where idproyecto=1 
group by actividad
```

y con esta consulta obtengo las tareas atrasadas por cada actividad:

```
select actividad,count(t.id) as tareas_actuales 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
where idproyecto=1 and t.estado='Pendiente' 
group by actividad.
```

Quiero que mi resultado sea así:

```
select actividad,count(t.id) as tareas_actuales,**count(t.id) as tareas_atrasadas** 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
where idproyecto=1 
group by actividad
```

<< count(t.id) as tareas_atrasadas  >> esto se obtiene con la misma consulta pero se adiciona la condicional where t.estado='Pendiente'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta esta muy bien estructurada, genial!!! La voy a editar para arreglar tu codigo, y creo que tengo una respuesta para vos

Comment: Podrias aclarar con que base de datos estas trabajando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos formas de resolver esto:

Una es usar lo que tenes ya listo, y armar otra consulta con las que tenes, de la siguiente forma:

```
select actaules.actividad, actuales.tareas_actuales, atrasadas.tareas_atrasadas 
from (
    select actividad,count(t.id) as tareas_actuales 
    from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
    where idproyecto=1 
    group by actividad) actuales left join
    (
    select actividad,count(t.id) as tareas_atrasadas 
    from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
    where idproyecto=1 and t.estado='Pendiente' 
    group by actividad) atrasadas on actuales.actividad = atrasadas.actividad
```

Uso en `left join`, porque si una tarea no tiene atrasadas, no la traeria, pero como queremos todas las tareas, necesitamos que todo lo que esta a la izquierda venga sin importar si esta o no a la derecha.

Ahora, esa consulta recorre la misma tabla 2 veces.. que pasa si lo hacemos ejecutandola una sola vez?

```
select actividad, count(t.id) as tareas_actuales, count( case when estado ='Pendiente' then 1 else 0 end) as tareas_atrasadas 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
where idproyecto=1 
group by actividad
```

Como no se tu base de datos, la sintaxis del case puede variar, pero la idea es recorrer la tabla una sola vez, y solo contar si cumple con esa condicion.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la primera me funciona bien, pero el inconveniente es que estoy programando con PHP framework Laravel y me dificulta mucho implementarlo, si fuera mucha molestia me gustaria que sea la 2da opción pero en MYSQL no me funciona

Comment: @DallanRamirezRoldan porque como puse en mi respuesta, la sintaxis para mysql del case no es esa.. ahora la modifico...

Comment: Acabo de verificar nuevamente y no me sale, estoy usando phpmyadmin

Comment: y que error te da?

Comment: Error
consulta SQL: Documentación


select actividad, count(t.id) as tareas_actuales, count( case estado when 'Pendiente' then 1 end case) as tareas_atrasadas 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id 
where idproyecto=1 
group by actividad LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'case) as tareas_atrasadas 
from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactivi' en la linea 1

Comment: Eso es un error de sintaxis.. y no parece que este mal la query. por lo menos yo no veo nada malo a simple vista. Igual la volvi a editar y le puse un else por si el problema es ese, pero parece que viene de otro lado el problema, algo le molesta del from.

Comment: Me salió, lo correcto es: select actividad, count(t.id) as tareas_actuales, count( case when t.estado ='Pendiente' then 1 end) as tareas_atrasadas  from tareas t right join actividades a on t.idactividad=a.id  where idproyecto=1  group by actividad

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada.. ahora edito la respuesta. Aclara que version de mysql usas, porque segun la documenta es end case. Y recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio!